# Idiom for CUDA class static member in device code?

Tags: c++, c++11, cuda, static-members, gpu

So, I've got a C++14 library that I'm porting to CUDA 9. I actually have (I think) a pretty good knowledge of CUDA, but I haven't done any direct work in it since CUDA 6.

Typically, I use a lot of templates and small classes in my code. It's surprised me that one still cannot have a `static __device__` class member in CUDA 9, but global variables are fine. Is there a good idiom or workaround for this? What do people typically do?

Edit: I should be clear, I mean specifically for templated classes. If the class isn't templated, it's pretty straightforward.

Edit 2: Here is some example code

In normal host-side C++ I do this:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
    static T my_static_member;
};
```

On the device, this won't compile, so what's a good equivalent?

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
    static __device__ T my_static_member;
};
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a list of all types for which MyClass is going to be specialized? Or would forming such a list be cumbersome and hard to track/maintain?

Comment: Yeah, it would be hard / impossible to maintain. I'm instantiating it for a lot of types and it's meant to be used in other libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use (templated) global variables instead of static members, and perhaps put them in a detail namespace:

```
namespace detail {
namespace MyClass {

template <typename T> __device__ T my_static_member;

} // namespace detail
} // namespace MyClass

template <typename T>
class MyClass {

    // ... you use detail::MyClass::my_static_member<T> in the code
};
```

... but not this will require passing `--std=C++14` to `nvcc`.

A further modification - a matter of style, basically - could be adding a not-technically-static-but-kind-of getter:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
    const T& my_static_member() const {
        return detail::MyClass::my_static_member<T>;
    }
    // ... you use my_static_member() in the code
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that does indeed work. I'm surprised that C++14 is really required for this, it seems like something that should be possible in NVCC and C++11. But this is a solid workaround.

Comment: Regarding "porting", I'm not new to CUDA or GPUs. Perhaps the word "porting" gives you the idea of something else. Maybe "enabling" makes more sense to you.

Comment: @user2333829: You could have several non-templated global variables  and then use a getter method which is specialized for different specific types, using specific globals. That's ugly but would most probably work.

Answer (score 3):

Your original code works if you [compile your CUDA with clang](https://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html).

Comment: Thanks! I'd rather stick with NVCC I think, though I do love clang.